# How to remove html from search autocomplete input after click on search results?

Tags: jquery, search, autocomplete

I am using auto complete wordpress plugin and facing issue after clicking on searching results. After clicking on results, HTML is also inserted to input text field.

How I can filter html content from this input text field?

Here is the URL of the website, if anyone needs to check problem.

URL - http://web1.kindlebit.com/DEVELOPMENT/levi_dev/company/apple-inc/?part=key_statistics

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question.

I removed the typo mistake error by commenting code at search-autocomplete.min.js file as below :--

b.html(b.text().replace(new RegExp("(" + d + ")", "gi"), '$1'))

to

b.html(b.text());

and did some changes to success function to pass my desired value to input search box at

return{label:a.title,value:a.title,url:a.url}

to

return { label: a.title,  value: a.id, url: a.url }

Where id is the custom key parameter passed to array containing the values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have check your website and review it. There is `typo` mistake in you `ul li a span` tag in search result;

Your `span` result generating like :

```
<sp<span class="sa-found-text 111">an cl<span class="sa-found-text 111">a</span>ss="symbol"&gt;WYNMY</sp<span>
```

that cause the issue

Comment: No, please check with different words like "abc"  and you will find there is no  typo mistakes there.